# PHP get file line by line and compare to string

Tags: php, string, list, file, compare

I have a file which is basically a list of names in that format:

```
name.lastname
name.lastname
name.lastname
myname.mylastname
name.lastname
```

and I want to check whether a string I have is equal to one of the names (with the dot).

Thats what I tried already:

```
$username = "myname.mylastname"; 
$boolean = False; 
$handle = fopen("thelist.txt","r");
while (($line = fgets($handle)) !== false) {
        if ($line === $username){
            $liste = True; 
        }
    }
```

after that list keeps being False and I dont know why.

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: I'd check if $line is returned as a string because you are using === try == and see if that returns true.

Comment: @DylanAnlezark I still get false unfortunatly. But what i found was that when i echo each $line, that there are spaces in between them although i wouldnt imagine that there should be spaces

Comment: Are you able to print out just before your if statement what `$line` is and what `$username` is and share that with us?

Comment: @DylanAnlezark for the first part of the loop i get "alexander.schmidt omar.remmo" and then later i get "nina.wietbrock omar.remmoomar.remmo omar.remmoozan.dincer omar.remmo"

Comment: Sorry I don't quite understand so does  "alexander.schmidt omar.remmo" = `$username`? And the other names = `$line`

Comment: @DylanAnlezark "alexander.schmidt" is the $line and "omar.remmo" is $username.
"echo $line;
 echo $username;" is what i wrote in my code in the loop

Comment: @DylanAnlezark The first one is what prints after the first go through of the loop and later is where $username and $line should be identical

Comment: What happens if instead of `if ($line === $username){` you hardcode the expected value of `if ("omar.remmo"=== $username){` do you then enter your if statement?

Comment: @DylanAnlezark Yes, then it works.

Comment: I still thinking that it has to do with the type of the data you are getting back from `fgets($handle)` What happens if you use `if ($line.toString() === $username){`

Comment: @DylanAnlezark then it crashes when it gets there. I dont get an error tho so i dont really know whats wrong

Comment: Can you add a screenshot of your echos that you are getting?

Comment: At least you can `trim()` whitespaces or check if each char is allowed, ie in range `a-zA-Z` while accepting the dot as valid one

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a few potential issues I see.

First `$boolean = False;` while `$liste = True;`, so you may have a potential typo in your output variable.

Second issue is that `thelist.txt` is not an absolute path. So the file resource may have failed to be loaded. It is highly recommended that you use an absolute path to file resources such as `/full/path/to/file` or `__DIR__ . '/path/to/file'`.

The main issue is that `fgets` will include the  `\r` and `\n` at the end of each line in the file, that does not exist in the compared string variable. You can use [`trim`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.trim.php) to remove extraneous line endings and white spaces to compare with the string variable.

### Example: https://3v4l.org/4VG4D

```
$username = "myname.mylastname"; 
$liste = false; 

$handle = fopen("thelist.txt", 'rb');
while (false !== ($line = fgets($handle))) {
    if (trim($line) === $username){
        $liste = true;
        break; //stop at first match
    }
}
fclose($handle);
var_dump($liste); //true
```